# Video not playing during window scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, multiscroll.js

I am trying to replicate the scroll video animation here on the site https://www.hamilton-medical.com/en_IN/Products/HAMILTON-C6.html#Drivingpressure

Have copied and modified the source code and uploaded my set of videos. Everything is the same apart from the video duration. I have updated the code and have seen that "data-duration" is the video duration in second and "data-scroll-length" is double of the video duration.  Image is preloaded before each video using CDN. But videos are not playing in our site https://cccsurgeryclinics.com/mediklik/banner-animation-test-copy.html. Can anyone please suggest where am I going wrong?

Here is the html of video code:

```
<video class="animation-segment" muted preload="auto" data-filepath-stub="videos/part-1-ham-c6" data-duration="3.2" data-scroll-length="6.4" data-keep-last-frame="" autobuffer>
                    <source src="videos/part-1-ham-c6-vp9.webm" type="video/webm; codecs=&quot;vp9&quot;">
                </video>

<video class="animation-segment" muted preload="auto" data-filepath-stub="videos/part-2-ham-c6" data-duration="2.0" data-scroll-length="4.0" data-keep-last-frame="" autobuffer>
                    <source src="videos/part-2-ham-c6-vp9.webm" type="video/webm; codecs=&quot;vp9&quot;">
                </video>

<video class="animation-segment" muted preload="auto" data-filepath-stub="videos/part-3-ham-c6" data-duration="4.8" data-scroll-length="9.6" data-keep-last-frame="" autobuffer>
                    <source src="videos/part-3-ham-c6-vp9.webm" type="video/webm; codecs=&quot;vp9&quot;">
                </video>

<video class="animation-segment" muted data-filepath-stub="videos/part-4-ham-c6" data-duration="4.5" data-scroll-length="9" data-keep-last-frame="">
                    <source src="videos/part-4-ham-c6-vp9.webm" type="video/webm; codecs=&quot;vp9&quot;">
                </video>

<video class="animation-segment" muted data-filepath-stub="videos/part-5-ham-c6" data-duration="4.0" data-scroll-length="8.0" data-keep-last-frame="">
                    <source src="videos/part-5-ham-c6-vp9.webm" type="video/webm; codecs=&quot;vp9&quot;">
                </video>

<video class="animation-segment" muted data-filepath-stub="videos/part-6-ham-c6" data-duration="3.0" data-scroll-length="6.0" data-keep-last-frame="">
                    <source src="videos/part-6-ham-c6-vp9.webm" type="video/webm; codecs=&quot;vp9&quot;">
                </video>

<video class="animation-segment" muted data-filepath-stub="videos/part-7-ham-c6" data-duration="3.0" data-scroll-length="6.0" data-keep-last-frame="">
                    <source src="videos/part-7-ham-c6-vp9.webm" type="video/webm; codecs=&quot;vp9&quot;">
                </video>
```